# Stop Relative Positioned Div Overlapping Other Divs

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have three divs stacked on top of each other (top, middle, bottom).  In the middle div, I have an image crossfade using Javascript adapted from [this fiddle by jfriend00](https://jsfiddle.net/volterony/4ycxayb2/).

The middle div has the position set to relative and the images within are all set to absolute. However what is happening is that that middle div is overlapping the bottom div.

I have mostly read that to contain absolutely positioned elements you must use a relative container, which I've used, however, I don't understand why my middle div is not flowing and stacking nicely between the top and bottom divs?

If I add a static height of 583px and width of 940px to the container, it flows correctly but doesn't respond.  Ideally, it needs to work with a percentage width.

Here is what I have tried:

```
.container {position: relative; font-size: 0; width: 100%;}

/*.container {position: relative; font-size: 0; height: 940px; width: 583px;} this stops the box responding, which isn't what I want */

.slide {
border: none; 
opacity: 0; 
position: absolute; 
width: 100%;
top: 0; 
left: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear;
-moz-transition: opacity 2s linear;
-o-transition: opacity 2s linear;
transition: opacity 2s linear;
}

.showMe {opacity: 1;}

.top {display: block;}

.bottom {display: block;}



<div class="top">
        This is some test content. Top.
</div>

<div class="container">
   <img id="slideimg0" class="slide showMe" src="https://dummyimage.com/940x583/red/fff.jpg">
   <img id="slideimg1" class="slide" src="https://dummyimage.com/940x583/000000/fff.jpg">
   <img id="slideimg2" class="slide" src="https://dummyimage.com/940x583/6b6b24/fff.jpg">
   <img id="slideimg3" class="slide" src="https://dummyimage.com/940x583/fefe03/fff.jpg">
   <img id="slideimg4" class="slide" src="https://dummyimage.com/940x583/094fae/fff.jpg">
   <img id="slideimg5" class="slide" src="https://dummyimage.com/940x583/fa132e/fff.jpg">
   <img id="slideimg6" class="slide" src="https://dummyimage.com/940x583/a90cba/fff.jpg">
</div>

<div class="bottom">
        This is some test content. Bottom.
</div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/volterony/4ycxayb2/) to demonstrate the problem.

Would really appreciate any help with this one.

Comment: Add static height to your middle element and it will start taking up space and pushing bottom block down. Middle block is of 0 height due to absolute elements inside of it not taking up any space. (Absolute elements don't take up space or push anything around them)

Comment: If I add a static height of 583 it clears the bottom div but it creates a big gap below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here! Just make one of the slides relatively positioned, so that it can give its parent container its height!

https://jsfiddle.net/4ycxayb2/3/

Just add this:

```
.slide:last-child {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Aw man, that's awesome.  Something as simple as that.  Very well done sir.  Fixes the problem!!!

Comment: Yeah, the problem was that the middle element wasn't taking up any space. It had no height, because all its content was absolutely positioned. Nice solution!

Comment: Yep. The only problem with this is slides have to be the same size :) otherwise a bit of javascript is needed

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want ?

```js
var timer = setInterval(nextImage, 4000);
var curImage = 0;
var numImages = 7;

function nextImage() {
  var e;
  // remove showMe class from current image
  e = document.getElementById("slideimg" + curImage);
  removeClass(e, "showMe");

  // compute next image
  curImage++;
  if (curImage > numImages - 1) {
    curImage = 0;
  }

  // add showMe class to next image
  e = document.getElementById("slideimg" + curImage);
  addClass(e, "showMe");
}

function addClass(elem, name) {
  var c = elem.className;
  if (c) c += " "; // if not blank, add a space separator
  c += name;
  elem.className = c;
}

function removeClass(elem, name) {
  var c = elem.className;
  elem.className = c.replace(name, "").replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ""); // remove name and extra blanks
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide {
  border: none;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 2s linear;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}

.showMe {
  opacity: 1;
}

.top {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.bottom {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

<div id="container">
  <img id="slideimg0" class="slide showMe" src="https://dummyimage.com/940x583/red/fff.jpg">
  <img id="slideimg1" class="slide" src="https://dummyimage.com/940x583/000000/fff.jpg">
  <img id="slideimg2" class="slide" src="https://dummyimage.com/940x583/6b6b24/fff.jpg">
  <img id="slideimg3" class="slide" src="https://dummyimage.com/940x583/fefe03/fff.jpg">
  <img id="slideimg4" class="slide" src="https://dummyimage.com/940x583/094fae/fff.jpg">
  <img id="slideimg5" class="slide" src="https://dummyimage.com/940x583/fa132e/fff.jpg">
  <img id="slideimg6" class="slide" src="https://dummyimage.com/940x583/a90cba/fff.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I.g. karlos.  I can see that by moving the middle div to the bottom that this solves the problem, but I will have other divs below